# WCF XML information is not displaying on live server

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have created a WCF Serive. When i deployed on local testing server it is displaying xml information. But when i try to deployed on live server it is not displaying XML information on Live server. My local testing url is [Test URL](http://122.176.113.4:8094/MeridianService.svc) when i click on [Link](http://122.176.113.4:8094/MeridianService.svc?wsdl) it is displaying my function xml information. But When i deployed on live it is not displaying xml information [Live URL](https://awc_xcbl.fastmilelogistics.com/MeridianService.svc). My local server is http and live is https.

Web config service model

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client />
<services>
  <service name="xCBLSoapWebService.MeridianService">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="xCBLSoapWebService.IMeridianService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMeridianService">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="52428800" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Can you help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking the link, it seems that you have found a solution to this issue, we have to set up the below code snippets to expose the service metadata over HTTPS.

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

One more thing we need to pay attention to is that we must configure the additional service endpoint to enable the service available over HTTPS since the server only enabled Https protocol.
Please refer to the below code.

```
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpsbinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="httpsbinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: lastly your <protocolMapping> part helped me . thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely a result of HTTPS requiring 'httpsGetEnabled' to be enabled.

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```